Add svg favicon in nextjs14
I can't make an svg work as a favicon. I tried moving it to public and app folders, changing its name in accordance with docs to icon and favicon. I still get 404 for favicon.ico in network tab. I also tried tinkering with metadata constant but still to no avail.
I have this in _document.tsx:
import { Html, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import Head from 'next/head'

export const metadata = {
    icons: {
        icon: '/favicon.svg'
    }
}

export default function Document() {
    return (
        <Html lang='ru'>
            <Head>
                <link rel='icon' href='/favicon.svg' />
                <meta name='apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style' content='#ff7652' />
            </Head>
            <body>
                <Main />
                <NextScript />
            </body>
        </Html>
    )
}


favicon should has .ico extension file in public folder.
favicon.ico

The task is to make an svg image the icon file. Docs describe how to do that but they seem to be erroneous or incomplete since it's appears to be not enough to make it work.

As much as I knows about the Next.Js 14 App Router there is no _document.tsx.

You should convert the .svg to .ico by using converter(Google it).
If it still doesn't show up delete the .next/cache folder and hard reload the tab, which you can by opening developer tool(inspect mode) and right clicking on reload button in the context menu you will find it.
